# Hg Mercurial over Google Drive issue

Tags: mercurial

I have a [Mercurial-Hg](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) repository on a Google Drive folder. I use it as a base repo to be used on few computers. Using [Tortoise-Hg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) in all of them.

It used to work fine like a charm, but last week I got a trouble I don't understand: doing normal operation (local commmit, hg push, hg pull from other local repo...) I got an error with Google Drive user. I fixed it and since then local repos diverge. I have tried many HG tricks (revert, back-out, creating new local repos...) but... the fact is:

- In computer 1: I create a new clone and last rev is 314.
- In computer 2: I create a new clone and last rev is 311. Last 3
  revisions are missing!!! How is this possible?

Apparently Google drive folder is synchronized correctly (I tested it creating a new dummy file in computer 1 and having it synchronized to computer 2).

How is this possible? Any hint? Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the Google Drive location as your LOCAL repository? Or are you only using it as a centralized repo which other locations can sync with?

Comment: Check the changeset ID, not the revision number. The changeset ID would look like 5760fdcf0793 and is guaranteed to be unique and unchanging. The revision number can vary from clone to clone which is normal.

Comment: @DaveInCaz I use it as a centralized repo. Then I clone local repos on local folders. Revision number may vary, right. But commit comments should remain the same. That's how I know I miss 3 last revisions. Don't understand why, yet...

Comment: Do you have some changesets which are SECRET and therefore not pushed to the central repo?

Comment: **DO NOT** under any circumstances use any kind of file-level synchronization tool, such as Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, Jottacloud, or any other such tool, to synchronize distributed version control repositories between computers. These tools only detect conflicts on a file-level and does not treat a repository (which is a collection of files and folders) as a unit that needs to have integrity *together*. Basically you've committed or changed something in your repository on a different computer before Google Drive had a chance to bring it up to date.

Comment: You should move your repository out of Google Drive, fix it, run an integrity check on it, and then set up a proper distributed version control repository somewhere that you can push/pull against.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What are you talking about?  I've used rsync to keep different copies of a git repo in sync, and all my research suggests that this is in fact safe.

Comment: @Michael Try that after making commits in both repositories. If you can avoid that you should be good, but there are plenty of people on the internet that have managed to not avoid that. I don't know how rsync deals with conflicting changes, but the cloud solutions tends to "resolve" this automatically, either by overwriting files and thus losing changes (jottacloud sync) or renaming conflicting copies (google drive/dropbox), neither of which will be helpful for your repository.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah... ok, making commits in both repositories hadn't occurred to me.  I'm using rsync to back the repo up to an old device (WD MyCloud) which doesn't have an easy way to install Mercurial on it.

Comment: It might be easier to avoid pitfalls with rsync, if that is more of a manual thing you do. The cloud synchronization tools happens in the background, and will "resolve" conflicts automatically. You're not guaranteed to have problems if you can manage to do things the "right way", but there's been enough people tripped by these conflict resolution algorithms that it's generally advised not to use them, and instead just rely on a central repository copy, such as github or gitlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-answered question. Just in case it can be useful for someone else:

@Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen comments are absolutely right:

> DO NOT under any circumstances use any kind of file-level
> synchronization tool, such as Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive,
> Jottacloud, or any other such tool, to synchronize distributed version
> control repositories between computers. [...]
>
> You should move your repository out of Google Drive, fix it, and then set up a proper distributed version control repository somewhere that you can push/pull against.

Done! Cloned from one of the diverging Google drive folders Drive to a brand-new [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) repo (configured as HG-Mercurial repo). It was very straight-forward to do.

Then re-cloned back from Bitbucket to all the computers where the repo was used. Google Drive folders abandoned.

Now all repos clones are working fine again! ...I wonder why I didn't do that before with this old repo. Actually I realize it's a MUST.

Comment: As I understand, you switch from Google Drive to Bitbucket and start distributing your code over Bitbucket, right? @MarcM

Comment: Correct @alper.

Comment: But... Bitbucket stopped supporting Mercurial... where did you go for free hosting then?

Comment: Notice that this post is getting older. At some point, after the post, I moved all the repos to a more 'modern' platform.